# Laravel email queue with different «from» parameters not working all the time

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 7, with queues and supervisor, and I have the following mail class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class Invoice extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $item;

    public function __construct($item)
    {
        $this->item = $item;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        $this->from('noreply@mydomain.com', $this->item->subscription->name)
            ->to($this->item->to['email'], $this->item->to['name'])
            ->subject($this->item->subject)
            ->replyTo($this->item->subscription->email, $this->item->subscription->name)
            ->view('mails/invoice')
            ->with('item', $this->item);

        if ($this->item->bcc)
            $this->bcc($this->item->bcc);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use the function `->from($email, $name)` to specify the header. The `noreply@mydomain.com` is permanent/fixed, but the `$name` isn't. It always tries to grab the subscription name.

What happens is that sometimes this works and sometimes it doesn't and I can' figure out why.

I want the emails to be sent always with the header according to my clients subscription name:

```
Google Company «noreply@mydomain.com»
Facebook Company «noreply@mydomain.com»
```

But sometimes it sends like this:

```
My SaaS Software «noreply@mydomain.com»
```

Because it grabs the content of the `.env` file. What I don't understand is why sometimes it works perfectly and sometimes it doesn't.

The variable `$this->item->subscription` content always exists. If it didn't exists, the `replyTo()` would also cause problems, which never causes.

**EDIT**:

The `item` variable contains the following:

```
$item = new \stdClass;
$item->invoice = $invoice;
$item->subscription = $subscription;
$item->subject = $subject;
$item->message = $message;
$item->to = $to;
$item->bcc = $bcc;

\Mail::queue(new \App\Mail\Invoice($item));
```

**EDIT 2**:

After applying the `log::debug`, the error occurred today and in the log it shows correctly:

```
Client Name «noreply@mydomain.com»
```

But the email received (i put my personal email as BCC) has the `from` as:

```
My SaaS Software «noreply@mydomain.com»
```

Comment: you can log the `$item` you are passing on the build method, then manually trigger the email which supposed to have issue, and check the data if they contain what you are pulling

Comment: If you inspect the mail object that is being sent, can you verify it does have the name it should have? If you get the wrong name in your mail client, it’s more a problem with that particular client that links the mail with the name for future reference, it works like a cache. Any change to that name doesn’t always reflect in the mail client. Also inspect the emails raw content if the information is really what it should be, and not just displayed incorrectly by the said client.

Comment: @silver I just added some logs but I'll have to wait to see the error happening again, because when I test it, it works all the time.

Comment: @dbf just added some logs, but one thing I've read, dunno if true, is that if the `->from()` is defined in the constructor it might help (?). I also though about instead of passing the data through `$this->item->subscription->name`, pass it as an variable like `$this->subscription_name`

Comment: how are you calling that mailable and is that `$item` queried fresh from db? can you post your code where you construct that `$item` you pass and deploy the mailable

Comment: @silver just eddited my post. The `$item` is an object containing different things. I have applied the debug as you suggested me, but I'm still waiting for this not to work, it takes time... xD

Comment: @silver the error just occurred today. The log debug shows the name correctly, however, when the email is received it's going as `My SaaS Software «noreply@mydomain.com»`.

Comment: @dbf read please what I told silver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved (?)**.

I have read somewhere someone suggesting that some fields should be passed as an argument and apply it in the `__construct`, in case there were problems with `queue`.

So far, from all the emails I have seen, everything is working. The expected result is visible, it shows as: `SomeCompany LTD «noreply@mydomain.com»`

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class Invoice extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $item;

    public function __construct($item)
    {
        $this->item = $item;
        
        // Initialize the <from> here & pass as an argument
        $this->from($item->from['email'], $item->from['name']);
    }

    public function build()
    {
        $this->to($this->item->to['email'], $this->item->to['name'])
            ->subject($this->item->subject)
            ->replyTo($this->item->subscription->email, $this->item->subscription->name)
            ->view('mails/invoice')
            ->with('item', $this->item);

        if ($this->item->bcc)
            $this->bcc($this->item->bcc);

        return $this;
    }
}
```